# Finding $P(X\leq 2Y)$ for joint pdf

Tags: probability, integration

> > $$f_{x,y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{4}{3}(2-x)y, & 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\\
> > 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
> >     Obtain $P(X\leq 2Y)$. Sketch the region of integration.

Is this the correct way to solve it?

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2y}\frac{4}{3}(2-x)y,dy\,dx$$

Or do I need to make it so that it is:

$$P(Y\leq \frac{x}{2})$$

And then solve form there? 
And how can I sketch the region of integration once I have solved it?

Comment: @stud_iisc shouldn't the $dx$ be second?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma This integration region is $0\leq y \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq 2y$. Or one could work with the region $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $x/2 \leq y \leq 1$ and get the same result for $P(X\leq 2Y)$.

Comment: @stud_iisc I concur

Comment: @stud_iisc The formula in your first comment is wrong (the upper limit $2y$ of the inner integral should read $\min\{2y,1\}$). The integration region described in the first sentence of your second comment is wrong for the same reason. The region described in the second sentence of your second comment is correct. One could find infortunate these confusions...

Comment: @Did Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I saw Mr. Graham's answer but didn't correct my comment.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In the first region $x \in [0,\min\{2y,1\}].$

Answer (score 1):

So you need to integrate over [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RegionPlot%5Bx+%3C+2y,%7Bx,0,1%7D,%7By,0,1%7D%5D) region.
This can be done by first freely choosing $x\in [0,1]$ then making $y$ vary :
$$
\int_0^1 dx \left( \int_{x/2}^1 dy\ f(x,y) \right)
$$
Or you can first choose $y$ and then $x$ but here we need to be careful since how $x$ will vary as function of $y$ must be split into two cases, when $y \in[0,1/2]$ or $y \in]1/2,1]$ :
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2} dy \left( \int_0^{2y} dx\ f(x,y) \right) + \int_{1/2}^{1} dy \left( \int_0^{1} dx\ f(x,y) \right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in conjunction with the event $x<2y$, the support is bounded by $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$, so in our integral, $x$ cannot exceed the minimum of $2y$ or $1$.

We thus need to split the integral into two parts.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<2Y)~&=~\int_0^1\int_0^{\min\{2y,1\}}\tfrac{4}{3}(2-x)y\operatorname d x\operatorname dy \\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2y} \tfrac 43(2-x)y\operatorname d x\operatorname d y+\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^1 \tfrac 43(2-x)y\operatorname d x\operatorname dy\end{align}$$

But, yes, you can take the alternate path

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y>X/2)~&=~\int_0^1\int_{x/2}^1\tfrac{4}{3}(2-x)y\operatorname d y\operatorname dx\end{align}$$

Whichever you find easier to integrate.